# An more elegant way to query MongoDB in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am fairly new to Ruby and MongoDB in particular. I use Mongo in a Ruby script to store and process thousands of Tweets in a collection. I would love to improve legibility and "rubyness" of the find command here:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

db      = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost").db("db")
coll    = db.collection("tweets")

cursor = coll.find({
   'geo_enabled' => true,
   'status.text' => { '$exists' => true },
   'followers_count' => {
   '$gte'   => 10,
   '$lt'    => 100 }
})

cursor.each_with_index { |row,idx|
  # do stuff
}
```

The mongodb query syntax drives me nuts! Is there a more elegant, ruby-like way to do a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/), it has nice syntax for queries, much similar to that of ActiveRecord/ActiveRelation.

Comment: Thanks! Will try! However, I have trouble getting the gem installed... `sudo gem install mongoid bson_ext` infinitely hangs at `Installing ri documentation for mongoid-2.2.0...`… what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can try to install the gem without documentation `sudo gem install mongoid bson_ext --no-ri --no-rdoc`

Comment: I fear my ruby setup is hosed; a demo.rb script instantly throws `uninitialized constant Mongoid (NameError)`, even though I do `require` mongo and mongoid. Could this be because all of my endeavours are outside of (potentially? broken) Rails context? And… I value your help, let me know if you think I should post this as another question. K? THX

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong with you code without looking at it. Please post and example of your demo.rb file, maybe as another question.

Comment: Again, thank you! I created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371003/mongoid-newbie-cant-get-it-to-work).