# gem-install of mongoid throws an uninitialized constant in Ruby, works in irb

Tags: ruby, mongodb, terminal, mongoid

I am writing a script with Ruby/MongoDB that stores Tweets. After I gem-installed **mongoid**, this first-steps code throws an error:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongoid'

Mongoid.database = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost').db('db')
# snippet from http://rujmah.posterous.com/using-mongoid-without-rails
```

NB. This is **no Rails app**, but a Terminal script.
The error I get is:

```
./mongoid.rb:10: uninitialized constant Mongoid (NameError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from mongoid.rb:3
```

It works in irb and I'm running ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0].

What am I doing wrong?

#### Edit August 2012

Somehow I got it to work. Alas, nearly a year on, I really can’t remember how. I will try to do better next time.

Comment: were you able to run the snippet from irb..?

Comment: BTW which version you are using. Works fine for me actually

Comment: `ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]`

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue while trying to get `Bullet` gem to work. The solution for me was to simply move `gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'` as the first line of the Gemfile. I find it really odd but that was how I got rid of that error.

I am using Ruby 2.1.0 and Rails 4.0.0